# Error in Shiny (R Package): "Error: invalid first argument"

Tags: r, shiny, random-forest

I am using Shiny and R to dynamically show a predicted value based on inputs put into Shiny by a user and a model based on existing data.  However, in the predicted output section, I am receiving the following error:
"invalid first argument."  Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is my first real foray into R and Shiny.  Below is my R code:

```
#shiny ui build
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel(
    tags$b(h1("Predict"))
        ),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      tags$style("body{background-image: url('Picture.jfif'); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat"),
      tags$style(".well{background-color:#D0D0D0}"),
      submitButton(text="Compute!"),
      h2("Answer"),
      textOutput("Answer"),
      "Units",
      br(),
      h6("Powered by:"),
      img(src="RStudio-Ball.png",height=35,width=35,alight="Left")
      ),
    mainPanel(
      tags$style(".well{background-color:#D0D0D0}"),
      h2("Enter information"),
      selectInput("Var.F","Select the input Var F",choices=levels(ExistingData$Var.F)),
      dateInput("Var.D","Enter input Var D",value=NULL),
      selectInput("Var.P","Select the input Var P",choices=levels(ExistingData$Var.P)),
      selectInput("Var.O","Select the input Var O",choices=levels(ExistingData$Var.O)),
      selectInput("Var.G","Select the input Var G",choices=c("A","B")),
      selectInput("Var.C","List Var C",choices=c("CA","DI","S"),multiple=TRUE),
      numericInput("Var.H","Enter H Value",value=5),
      numericInput("Var.W","Enter W Value",value=10),
      br()


    )
    )
  )
)


#shiny server
library(shiny)

#############
library(httr)
set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L))
library(DomoR)
set.seed(1000)
DomoR::init('x123','x12345')

#Get new data
ExistingData <- fetch('x') #This is a call to Domo to get the data set "ExistingData"

#Set Factors
ExistingData$Var.F <- as.factor(ExistingData$Var.F)
ExistingData$Var.P <- as.factor(ExistingData$Var.P)
ExistingData$Var.O <- as.factor(ExistingData$Var.O)
ExistingData$Var.G <- as.factor(ExistingData$Var.G)
ExistingData$Var.DI <- as.factor(ExistingData$Var.DI)
ExistingData$Var.S <- as.factor(ExistingData$Var.S)
ExistingData$Var.CA <- as.factor(ExistingData$Var.CA)

#Compute age
ExistingData$Var.T <- (ExistingData$T2 - ExistingData$T1)
ExistingData$Var.T <- as.numeric(ExistingData$Var.T)

#Random Forest
library(randomForest)
RF.x <- as.data.frame(ExistingData[,c("Var.A","Var.F","Var.P","Var.O","Var.G","Var.DI","Var.W","Var.H","Var.B","Var.S","Var.CA")])
set.seed(1000)
RF.1 <- randomForest(y=ExistingData$Answer,x=RF.x,importance=TRUE,ntree=5)

#Shiny specific language

shinyServer(function(input,output){

  Var.T <- reactive({Sys.Date()-input$D})
  Var.F <- reactive({input$Var.F})
  Var.P <- reactive({input$Var.P})
  Var.O <- reactive({input$Var.O})
  Var.G <- reactive(as.factor(ifelse(input$Var.G=="A",1,0)))
  Var.DI <- reactive({as.factor(max(ifelse(grepl("DI",input$Var.C),1,0)))})
  Var.W <- reactive({input$Var.W})
  Var.H <- reactive({input$Var.H})
  Var.B <- reactive({(Var.H - Var.W)})
  Var.S <- reactive({as.factor(max(ifelse(grepl("S",input$Var.C),1,0)))})
  Var.CA <- reactive({as.factor(max(ifelse(grepl("CA",input$Var.CA),1,0)))})

i.df <- reactive({
    data.frame(Var.A=as.numeric(Var.A()),
    Var.F=as.factor(Var.F()),
    Var.P=as.factor(Var.P()),
    Var.O=as.factor(Var.O()),
    Var.G=as.factor(Var.G()),
    Var.DI=as.factor(Var.DI()),
    Var.W=as.numeric(Var.W()),
    Var.H=as.numeric(Var.H()),
    Var.B=as.numeric(Var.B()),
    Var.S=as.factor(Var.S()),
    Var.CA=as.factor(Var.CA())
    )

    })
  output$Answer <- reactive({predict(RF.1,i.df())[1]})


  })
```

EDIT: I fixed the i.df in output$Answer so that it is i.df().  I'm now receiving an error of "Type of predictors in new data do not match that of the training data."

Comment: Could it be because you need to refer to `i.df` as `i.df()` in `ouptut$answer`

Comment: That solved one problem, but it appears I uncovered a second:
"Type of predictors in new data do not match that of the training data."
I have a feeling I made my lists not match in the input...
I'll try to debug tomorrow.

Comment: You rock for finding the first thing though Balter!!